# "...is as much instinct as science"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Not a native English speaker.

**Question**: What does the following mean?

> Something is as much instinct as science.

For example, I was reading a post on a [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) Query Performance where I came across the following sentence. I'm not expecting the readers of this post to know SQL or Index Tuning, but just need to know what a sentence like this generally mean:

> Index tuning is as much instinct as science.

Ref: Last sentence of this **SO** [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/179129/1232087).

Comment: As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+much+instinct+as+science%2Cas+much+art+as+science&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows, we're much more likely to say something *is as much **art** as science*. But the meaning is the same anyway. Index tuning is a "creative" process, not something that you can do successfully just by following instructions. Not really true, obviously, but it's the kind of thing experts like to say (effectively, *I'm an **artist**, not just someone who follows instructions*).

Comment: Do you understand what "as much X as Y" means in general?

Comment: You may probably understand the following sentences : "Depression is as much physical as psychological" or "Something requires as much instinct as science". The construction "*as much <noun or adjective> as*" have the same sense in all sentences.

Comment: Please answer the question from @stangdon in your post. If you do understand the "as much X as Y" structure but still don't understand the sentence, then please explain what part of it is actually giving you difficulty. That will help you to get good answers.

Comment: @stangdon No, I don't know what "as much X as Y" means in general? Maybe, understanding it will help me understand `Index tuning is as much instinct as science.` I do (at least, I think) have understanding of `not so much x as y`.

Comment: You may use some online translator (from English towards your mother tongue) on my first example that uses words that are not too ambiguous : "Depression is as much physical as psychological".

Answer (score 2):

The sentence means that **one needs to use both intuition** (instinct) **and a proven methodology** (science) **for index tuning** in order to be good at it.

This might help you understand the sentence better:

> Index tuning is as much instinct as [it is] science.

The phrase *as much X as [it is] Y* is often used as an argument **to justify the speaker's decisions or choices** (often made based on their experience), or **to encourage the audience to consider the topic from a different perspective** (often, from the perspective of both X and Y), **or both**.

For example:

1. Teaching Is as Much an Art as a Science 
   https://www.edweek.org/education/opinion-teaching-is-as-much-an-art-as-a-science/2005/10
2. Is Design a Science or an Art? 
   https://wonderopolis.org/wonder/is-design-a-science-or-an-art

Meanwhile, in the case of your sentence, the person who made the statement is trying to help the person who asked the question by telling them that for index tuning, while there are best practices they could follow (science), it is just as much as a process of trial and error and learning from experience to hone one's intuition (instinct). Hope this helps.